# Tensorflow: How to handle preprocessing.Normalization returning NaN

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, normalization

I am building a keras model and trying to use the tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.Normalization from https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/experimental/preprocessing/Normalization to normalize the input training data as such:

```
normalize = preprocessing.Normalization()
normalize.adapt(trainX)
model = Sequential([
    normalize,
    Dense(dim + 1, input_dim=dim, activation="relu"),
    Dense(dim / 2, activation="relu"),
])
```

The goal is to save the normalization within the saved model. I am running into the issue where the `normalize(trainX)` is normalizing some of the inputs to `nan` due to most likely a division of zero in the variance. E.g. a row of the output: `[ 0.00000000e+00, nan, 9.40457404e-01, 9.40672755e-01, 9.40672755e-01, 9.40672755e-01, 9.40672755e-01, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]`

**Is there a way to handle division of zero in `preprocessing.Normalization()` or is this there another way of normalization I should consider that I can save within the model?**

Comment: It appears that the variance is zero for some datapoints. First of all, this itself is a little bit concerning. But if you know what you are doing, then one way to get around this is to add noise with a very small variance (e.g. 1e-8) to your data to make sure you don't get zero variance.